# LInux: How do I diagnose / isolate what's causing "random" hangs and spontaneous reboots?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, crash

*(originally posted on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/104354/linux-how-do-i-diagnose-isolate-whats-causing-random-hangs-and-spontaneous))*

So, rather than guessing just what the cause is (though my money's on the nvidia drivers), where do I start looking to pin down some facts?

I've been through /var/log on several occasions but there's a LOT of stuff in there and I can't (yet) spot the important bits.

**Background: The Short Version**

I moved from WinXP to Ubuntu Karmic just after it became available.

Since then I have had a series of *seemingly* random crashes that manifest as either:

- a spontaneous reboot
- a complete lockup with my USB keyboard and mouse becoming unresponsive (right down to he LEDs all turning off).  Also I will typically be unable to ssh to the box when this happens.

I've done plenty of searching and Nvidia seems to be the prime suspect but I have no idea where to start looking to work out just what the real cause is.

A serverfault user suggested checking the RAM with MemtextX86+.  No errors found.  Monitoring video card temperature has also been suggested, which I'm looking into now.

Other than than, suggestions anyone?

**Background: The Long Version**

At times, I can go an entire week without a crash then have 5 in 2 days.

Motivated by the desire to eliminate possible suspects, I've made a few changes over time to no avail:

- Originally I used KVM for virtualization, I now use VirtualBox OSE
- I had NFS running in the kernel but now use Samba
- I was using Compiz but have since turned that off
- I've rolled from 64-bit Karmic to 32-bit (for other reasons as well)
- I've tried Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Xubuntu.  Same trouble each time (although of late it seems to be more frequent in Gnome than in XFCE).
- I rolled the Nvidia driver from version 185 back  to version 96 (NVIDIA Linux x86 Kernel Module  96.43.13  Thu Jun 25 18:42:21 PDT 2009).  This *seems* to have reduced the frequency of error.

In terms of what's running at the time, this can vary.  The following are common but were not necessarily running for every crash:

- Firefox 3.5
- VirtualBox OSE with 1 or 2 Windows XP VMs
- Skype
- Rhythmbox or Exaile

My hardware is 2 - 3 years old:

- Core 2 Duo 6300
- 4GB RAM
- some breed of Intel motherboard of that vintage
- an Asus dual-head video card with Nvdia GeForce 7300 GS chipset
- 2 x SATA HDDs
- dual monitors (hence I rely on the proprietary nvidia drivers)

I've been keeping current with my system updates.

Hopefully the data above might prompt someone to suggest a specific type of log or config that would be worth investigating.

**Update 1**

just had a crash in which the speakers went nuts.  Did some googling and it seems PulseAudio has had a few issues in the past.  Not sure yet if this is relevant but PulseAudio will have been running every time I had a crash.

**Update 2**

Following @CarlF's link to the Debian Sysadmin Guide has lead me to the magic sysrq key which I shall try at the next crash.  Not that this'll give me much clues as to the cause but at least I'll hopefully be able to shutdown gracefully.

**Update 3**

lm-sensors reports my GPU running at nearly 70C / 158F - interesting.  If I had to guess I'd say this is an important clue.

**Update 4**

Hit the insides of the system with an airduster shortly after my last update - net result: only one crash since then.  I'm gonna call this a thermal problem.

Comment: Excellent formatting and background information, I wish all questions were like this. +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's good advice from the Debian Administrator's Guide here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140728070056/http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/492

Comment: Interesting to see what they have to say about non-informative logs being a sign of real hardware trouble.  I've a six hour gap between last /var/log/message entry and the reboot.  Hmmmm.

Comment: accepted on the grounds that the link made it clear that nothing in the logs equals hardware problem - lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you may want to check if there are hardware problems during boot. The bootup process will log data from the kernel ring buffer into `/var/log/boot.log`. After the system is booted, new messages are flushed into this buffer and you can view it's current state with the `dmesg` command. An important log you'll also want to investigate is `/var/log/messages`. This will contain timestamps, facilities, and the priorities of the errors and the application which generated them. Having a time stamp available is a priceless asset when debugging errors.

The random lockups definitely sound hardware related though. Try reseating all hardware on the motherboard and give it a [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) run.

Comment: I see a line in /var/log/messages that says "imklog 4.2.0, log source = /var/run/rsyslog/kmsg started".  Is this a good indicator of a system boot?  If so I can use that to pinpoint an area of the log I can scan back from.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's one of the first, if not the first line after a boot. It is the kernel log input module.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried re-seating your memory, processor, and other chips? Also, you may want to try running another OS (FreeDOS) to eliminate some possibilities.

As a tip, you should also be able to use two monitors quite nicely through Gnome without using the nvidia drivers.

Comment: best I've been able to tell I definitely need the nvidia propietary drivers to use dual monitors.  You able to point me in the right direction to not needing them?

Comment: I may be incorrect. I've poked around a bit, and see references to xinerama (which I think the driver has extensions for) but nothing relating to non-proprietary driverws. Unfortunately, I don't have a machine with an nVidia card to play around with.