# Linux: can a crazy mouse bring the kernel down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, mouse

related to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/106006/linux-how-do-i-diagnose-isolate-whats-causing-random-hangs-and-spontaneous) I asked recently, is it possible for a crazy usb device such as a mouse to bring the Linux kernel to its' knees?

I've got an Ubuntu Karmic box that experiences random restarts / complete freezes.  The discussion in my previous question is pointing to a hardware issue but it's not been pinned down just yet.

In the meantime, I've noticed that open windows can just start scrolling like crazy & I have to press the click wheel a few times to stop it.

So, can a 7 button (MS) optical USB mouse going scroll-crazy cause Linux to have a fit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely not.  Your better bet is to check the motherboard, ram, and cpu.  The Linux kernel is extremely robust and will maintain its stability very well, unless something major is causing problems, and that something major is usually one of the three (above).  If you can, I'd try swapping out the hardware with spares in the order of ram, cpu, motherboard to see if any of these are the cause, and you might find them causing the mouse problems as well, especially if it is the motherboard.